# Align three pictures in minipage at top - again

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

Hey awesome community!

I have this problem working with LaTeX. I got three pictures and want to align all of them at the upper egde of them, but none of the examples and answers I found could help me out.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[b][6cm][t]{5cm}}{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t,angle=90]{a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,valign=t,angle=90]{b}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=b]{c}
}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

With this, they're all next to eachother, but aligned at their bottom.
I'm sure you know where the big, stupid mistake is.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Order matters here. Remove the `adjustbox` environment, and use `valign=t` for all three. But move the `angle` to *before* the `valign`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90,valign=t]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,angle=90,valign=t]{example-image-b}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image-10x16}
\end{document}
```